# Working with columns - awk and sed

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am trying to parse a text file that is generated by an expec script that
pulls down some information from a switch.

Here is a sample output:

```
192      0000.0000.0000        1/g23      Dynamic              
192      0000.0000.0000        ch1        Dynamic              
192      0000.0000.0000        ch1        Dynamic              
192      0000.0000.0000        ch1        Dynamic
```

The text file has a lot of other junk in it that I am not interested in. I only want the lines that contain the switch number and the port - "1/g23" in the example above.

I did a grep on the file to extract the lines that contain the pattern '/g'
and it  works great.

Now all I want are the two middle columns.
I used awk to print the columns.

```
0000.0000.0000 1/g23
```

Now that that is done I want to get ride of the '.'
sed worked okay for this

```
000000000000 1/g23
```

From here I want to convert only the first column to a MAC address format.

```
So this
000000000000 1/g23
Becomes this
00:00:00:00:00:00 1/g23
```

I was able to find a sed command that would accomplish this. But my problem is I only need it done on the first column. I am not quite sure how I can edit only the one column and not lose the association between the MAC and the port.

```
grep -e "/g" switch6output | awk '{print $2,$3}' | sed 's/\.//g' | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//'
```

I'm sure this is a really stupid way of doing it, but it was the best I could come up with. Is there a more reliable way I can accomplish what I need without losing the MAC and port association?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use awk directly:

```
awk '/\/g/ {
        gsub(/\./, "", $2)
        gsub(/../, "&:", $2)
        sub(/:$/, "", $2) 
        print $2,$3
}'
```

With this solution you don't need `grep` nor `sed`.

Comment: This is awesome! Worked perfectly. Thank you!!!! Sorry to ask another dumb question. does the second gsub with "&:" put the semi-colon in the correct place? I was just trying to figure out the purpose of the "&". and the last sub removes the trailing semi-colon that is left over?

Comment: @bourne you are right - see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html `If the special character ‘&’ appears in replacement, it stands for the precise substring that was matched by regexp.`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am starting to understand it a little more. A friend of mine actually created a little script to test the use of the '&' and it is making it make more sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Only `sed` example:

```
sed -r '\=1/g23=!d;
        s/[^ ]* *//;
        s/ *[^ ]* *$//;
        s/(..)\.(..)/:\1:\2:/g;
        s/::/:/'
```

If your input contains tabs instead of spaces, you have to adjust the expressions.

Comment: Wow this is great.Thank you very much for the response. I had a little bit of a harder time following this one so I think I might use the awk. But I am going to try and figure out how you did it using this sed expression! Thank you again

Comment: @bourne: Here is another one for you to work out :) ... The $x and $d are just to aviod some of the clutter in the regex; and it caters for any port/switch value. If they are hex digits, just change $d to suit...  `x='(..)'; d='[0-9]+'; sed -rn "/$d\/g$d/{ s/\S+\s+$x$x\.$x$x\.$x$x\s+($d\/g$d).*/\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6 \7/p }" file`

Comment: @Peter.O Awesome thank you! I am learning a ton about how sed and awk work from this thread! I will work through both yours and choroba's suggestions so I can understand them better!